# android - Updating ListView from AsyncTask called from custom adapter class

Tags: android, android-asynctask, adapter

I am trying to update a ListView from an AsyncTask. I have this situation:

- Activity Class creates the list adapter from a custom Adapter class.
- Adapter class sets onClickListener on element from list item, and calls an AsyncTask located in a different Utilities class.

How can I call notifyDataSetChanged from onPostExecute() method in the Utilities AsyncTask?

Comment: you will send Adapter instance using Utilities class parametrized constructor for calling  `notifyDataSetChanged` in `onPostExecute` method. have u tried this way?

Comment: No, that is my question. How can I send the adapter instance in the constructor of the Utilities class? I know that it's a simple question, but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Include a *Delegate* as a callback to activate the refresh from within the original class.

For example, add this interface:

```
public interface AsyncDelegate {

    public void asyncComplete(boolean success);


}
```

Then, in your calling class, implement the interface, and pass it to your task

```
public class MyClass implements AsyncDelegate  {

// Class stuff
MyAsyncTask newTask = new MyAsyncTask(this);
newTask.execute();

public void asyncComplete(boolean success){
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

In the AsyncTask, return the result:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {

   private AsyncDelegate delegate;

   public MyAsyncTask (AsyncDelegate delegate){
     this.delegate = delegate;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      delegate.asyncComplete(true);
   }

}
```

When the task completes, it will call the delegate, which will trigger the refresh!

Comment: You may want to wrap your delegate into a WeakReference as MyClass probably is an activity or something else that may be recreated while your task is running (device orientation change e.g.).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

newslist is a ArrayList.
nAdapter is a generic adapter.

So first you clear your list, then add all your new content.
After, you says to your Adapter that your content have been changed.

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) {

        newsList.clear();
            newsList.addAll(list);
            nAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I know that I should call notifyDataSetChanged() in the onPostExecute() method. The problem is that I don't know how to pass an adapter instance in the AsyncTask, because they are not in the same class. If they were, I could just create a global adapter variable which I could then call within the AsyncTask.

Comment: you dont need to pass the adapter to asynctask, you need just create the variable exactly as you said.