# Android - modify adapter from the UI thread and not from background thread

Tags: android, ui-thread

I have a ListView populated from json and using custom adapter.

This is my shortened code in ZoznamActivity:

```
 public class Zoznam extends AppCompatActivity{

    private ArrayList<Actors> actorsList;
    private ActorAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   setContentView(R.layout.search_filter);
        final ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        actorsList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new ActorAdapter(this, "Zoznam", actorsList);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        new GetContacts(Zoznam.this).execute("all","all");

   private static class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog dialog;
        private final WeakReference<Zoznam> activityReference;

        GetContacts(Zoznam context) {
            activityReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Zoznam activity = activityReference.get();
            if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing()) return;
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
            dialog.setMessage(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.Loading));
            dialog.setTitle(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.connecting));
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... sText1) {final Zoznam activity = activityReference.get();


            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
            String url = "URL";
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    JSONArray actors = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");

                    for (int i = 0; i < actors.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = actors.getJSONObject(i);

                        Actors actor = new Actors();

                        actor.setLetter(c.getString("letter"));
                        actor.setNazov(c.getString("nazov"));
                        actor.setThumb(c.getString("thumb"));


                        activityReference.get().actorsList.add(actor);

                    }

                }  catch (final JSONException e) {

                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(activity,
                                    R.string.Nodata,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }); }

return jsonStr;

            } else {
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(activity,
                                R.string.Network,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                return null;
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Zoznam activity = activityReference.get();
            if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing()) return;
            dialog.dismiss();
            activity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            super.onPostExecute(result);

        }

    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

The problem is, in crash reports I have found this error:

The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes.

However it happened only once for one device yet, but I'd like to fix this.

I have read more threads about this, but I still don't have a solution. As you can see in my code, I am calling notifyDataSetChanged() also onPostExecute, so not sure where is the problem.

Comment: Not sure will this fix the issue but you are calling `activity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` before calling `super.onPostExecute(result);` Also you don't need UIThread calls `activity.runOnUiThread` inside `doInBackground` you can do all of that inside `onPostExecute`

Comment: yes, I switched the order in onPostExecute to test it, but it works also like it is now. I can't reproduce the issue, on my device it is always working. The exception appeared only once on one device. So what else should I do in onPostExecute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `AsyncTask` so that you compute the list inside `doInBackground()` and then return it to `onPostExecute()`, and then do all of your updates there:

```
// change the type parameters to return a List
private static class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Actors>> {

    @Override
    protected List<Actors> doInBackground(Void... ignored) {
        // add this at the top
        List<Actors> actors = new ArrayList<>();

                    // inside your loop, replace this line:
                    // activityReference.get().actorsList.add(actor);
                    // with this instead
                    actors.add(actor);

        // and at the end, return the list
        return actors;
    }

    // the list you returned from doInBackground() is passed here
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Actors> result) {
        // update your activity all at once in this method
        activity.actorsList.clear();
        activity.actorsList.addAll(result);
        activity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

I've trimmed out a bunch of code to make things easier to read, but the general idea is there.

Comment: thank you, I forgot to change last parameter to List<Actors> in Getcontacts before. In your code I think we should change also protected String doInBackground to protected List<Actors> doInBackground and this way it is working. I will check in future release if the issue will appear after this change, but hopefully not.

Comment: Whoops, yes, you're absolutely right, `doInBackground()` must return `List<Actors>`

Answer (score 1):

You probably got the exception because you updated the adapter list on the background thread.

`activityReference.get().actorsList.add(actor);` This line in `doInBackground` method is updating the actual list you've passed to the adapter. All this calculation in `doInBackground` must be happening pretty fast and `notifyDataSetChanged` from `onPostExecute` is getting called. I'm not sure how, but this one time your `onPostExecute` wasn't called in time hence your list was updated but your `ListView` didn't receive the notification.

You can create a local list in your `AsyncTask` and update the activity's list in `onPostExecute`. Sample code -

```
private static class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    ArrayList<Actors> actors = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sText1) {
        ...
        for (int i = 0; i < actors.length(); i++) {
            ...
            // activityReference.get().actorsList.add(actor); <-- remove this.
            actors.add(actor);
        }
        ...
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Zoznam activity = activityReference.get();
        if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing()) return;
        dialog.dismiss();
        activityReference.get().actorsList.add(actors); <-- add this
        activity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

This should work, but you can further improve your code by using callbacks. That way you won't have to keep a reference of the activity inside the asyncTask and you can move all the logic out of the asyncTask. This answer should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/15693380/6168272.

Comment: I am not sure how to create a custom list there, but what if I do it this way inside the for cycle:             activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                activityReference.get().actorsList.add(actor);
                                activity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });

Comment: Don't do this, it will be an un-optimized code. By a local list, I meant to create a new ArrayList inside your AsyncTask. I'll add some sample code.

Comment: when I added to the for cycle this: actors.add(actor); then it says can't resolve method add. And in postexecute I added  activityReference.get().actorsList.add(actors); and it says can't resolve actors.